# Makefile with multiple files always builds everything

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I am writing a Makefile which compiles a number of C files, some in the same directory as the Makefile and others in parent directories (must be there for historic reasons). I want to put all *.o files in a single directory (objdir in my case). This seems to work, but for some reason, this Makefile always builds everything, even if nothing has changed. Where am I going wrong in my rules/dependecies?

UPDATE: I've distilled my Makefile and sources down to the bare minimum (see below for source file contents. To be clear, this does compile and link. The problem is that it does the compilation and linking every time I run make, even if nothing has changed. This is not typical make behavior.

Makefile contents:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror -I..
SRCS = main.c ../a.c
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, objdir/%.o, $(SRCS))
LN_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, objdir/%.o, $(notdir $(SRCS)))
MAIN = foo

.PHONY: clean

default: objdir $(MAIN)
    @echo  Done

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(LN_OBJS    )

objdir/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o objdir/$(notdir $@)

objdir:
    @mkdir -p objdir

clean:
    @$(RM) -rf objdir $(FDP) $(DK)
```

main.c contents

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#include "a.h"

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    a();
}
```

../a.c contents

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a()
{
    printf("Hi from a\n");
}
```

../a.h contents

```
#ifndef __a__
#define __a__

void a();

#endif
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I suggest you reduce your makefile to a minimal example, and post that, along with the output you see.

Comment: I've updated the question with a simplified example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule for `objdir/%.o:` is expanded to `objdir/../a.o: ../a.c`, but you then go and create `objdir/$(notdir $@)`, violating rule 2 of the [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).

One way to fix this is with `vpath` (also note that `objdir` should be a (order-only) dependency of the objects):

```
SRCS = main.c a.c
vpath %.c ../
# [...]
objdir/%.o: %.c | objdir
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```